# Android maps does not give merge highways

Tags: android, json, google-maps, routes, geocoding

Well i am making an app that uses google maps and routing, everything is working fine until now.
I am getting the 1st LatLng point("start_location") and the last LatLng point("end_location") for each instruction from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin

The problem is if I go on a highway I use http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? to get the name of the highway. But i lose the merging highways..

The only solution i am seeing is doing the polyline points but that takes too long because I need to analize TONS of points and that is not that efficient.

Is there any other solution to get merging highways? Any API besides maps/geocoding?

Comment: Polylines are the way to go from what I have seen with Android maps/custom navigation. Why do you need to perform analysis on the points of the polyline?

Comment: Because I want to get the name of the street, in this case the name of the highway and the only solution I see is analyzing all points so I know when they merge.